# give value if number is in column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have 5 persons, each wih a personal code beginning with PI. I receive tasks with a 2 digit number. I need to assign these tasks on the basis of these numbers:

[image: Example]

as you can see in the image, person pi299 has to get the tasks with the numbers in the column below. the number in this example is 70. this number changes every time. in this example the result should be pi20.

i've already tried multiple if statements with vlookup statements, but they all failed.

This will be part of a system that receives tasks and needs to assign them automaticaly according to the number. i need a formula that does this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the following formula will do what you expect, I've attempted to explicitly state the ranges, but these might require amending:

Range for Headers:$A$1:$E$1

Range for Data: $A$2:$E$500

Range for Number: $G$2

```
=INDEX($A$1:$E$1,SUMPRODUCT(MAX(($A$2:$E$500=$G$2)*(COLUMN($A$2:$E$500)))))
```

Comment: Genius! Thank you very much!

Comment: Works fine without `-COLUMN($A$1)+1`

Comment: One more question, the Number in the example as 70 is a formula. the output is wrong with this formula but correct if i just put a value in the cell, any suggestion?

Comment: @KeesKameel not sure, as I've tested it with and without a formula and it works for me on both examples...

Comment: Weird, if i manually put a value in the number cell then the formula works fine. but once i refer the number to the cell using a =(cell) forumla then the result is #value.

Comment: Found it, i used a LEFT Function which outputted a wrong value. i used the VALUE function to convert it back to a number.